# R: Using data frame column names as vector names

Tags: r

I am a fairly new R user (MATLAB convert) and am trying to name the variables in my data set using the column names that I've given the data set.

Let's say I've got a data frame called Z with three columns that I have named as below.

```
Header <- c("Date", "Time", "Data")
colnames(Z) <- Header
```

Is there a simple way to convert these column names to vector names so that when I type "Data" in the command line, the values from column 3 appear (and so I can call these names easily in a script)?

Thanks much in advance!

Comment: Not sure I understand... you want `attach`?  as in `attach(Z); Data`.  But I would strongly suggest against this.

Comment: I've named the columns of my data frame... now what I want to do is use those same column names as the names of the vector corresponding to the actual column of data.

Comment: Again, I don't understand and advise against this, but:  `sapply(names(z), function(x) assign(x, z[[x]], envir=.GlobalEnv))`.  The "R" way to do this is just to access them inside the `data.frame`: `x <- 'Data'; Z[[x]]`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of attach and detach functions with your data. I believe this is ok for interactive use, but it´s not best practice for programming. Probably, it´s not really recomendable to use at all, i believe i´ve never used it!

```
Z <- data.frame(matrix(rpois(9, 80), ncol = 3, nrow = 9))
head(Z)
> head(Z)
X1  X2  X3
1  69  69  69
2  80  80  80
3  69  69  69
4 103 103 103
5  65  65  65
6  81  81  81

# Use different names for each column!

Header <- c("Date_1", "Time", "Data_2")
colnames(Z) <- Header

head(Z)
 Date_1 Time Data_2
1   69   69   69
2   80   80   80
3   69   69   69
4  103  103  103
5   65   65   65
6   81   81   81


attach(Z)

Date_1
[1]  69  80  69 103  65  81  84  70  93

Time
[1]  69  80  69 103  65  81  84  70  93

detach(Z)

# Do not forget to detach! 
Time
Error: objeto 'Time' no encontrado
```

**Perhaps another option is using with:**

```
with(Z, Time)
# [1] 91 81 81 87 82 72 81 74 85

with(Z, quantile(Time))
#  0%  25%  50%  75% 100% 
#  72   81   81   85   91
```

**Or just subsetting each variable.**

```
# Subsetting keeping attributes
Z[2]
Z["Time"]

attributes(Z["Time"])
# $names
# [1] "Time"

# $class
# [1] "data.frame"

# $row.names
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

# Subsetting droping attributes
Z$Time
Z[["Time"]]

attributes(Z[["Time"]])
# NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Typically you access columns from a data frame using the '$' operator. In your case you'd want to use

```
Z$Data
```

to get the 'Data' vector. R has a function called 'attach()' that will essentially designate one data frame as your reference frame so that any variable you enter in the command line that matches a column head in your data frame will return that vector, ala

```
attach(Z)
Data
```

Would return the 'Data' vector. However, this is not recommended since keeping track of what frame is attached is not always easy and can have unintended consequences. If you wanted to create separate data vectors for each column that were independent of the data frame but with names identical to the column names you could do it like this:

```
Header <- c("Date", "Time", "Data")
for (i in 1:length(Header)){
  assign(Header[i], Z[ ,i])
  }
```

Though again I'd just use the '$' sign operator to access the columns from the data frame. Better than having two copies of the data floating around with similar names.

Comment: Thanks for all the responses, guys! I think I will use the '$' operator... this is a huge data set and it is unnecessary to have two copies of the data.

Comment: Please consider accepting an answer if this works for you. That way the question stops popping up as unanswered. Thanks.

Comment: The convention on SO is to wait a day before accepting an answer. Otherwise you are pretty much guaranteed no one else will look at it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `$` operator to call a column by name, or you can call a column by it's position in the data frame, in your example:

```
z$Data
```

or

```
z[3]
```

or

```
z[,3]
```

Are all the same.

Check out this reference card: http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Short-refcard.pdf. I can't tell you how many times it has helped my out when I was just beginning with R.